# Ставится ли запятая перед «как»?

Tags: пунктуация, как

1. Ты даже не представляешь() как я скучаю.
2. Жду тебя() как солнца лучик.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая нужна. **Ты даже не представляешь, как я скучаю.** — это придаточное образа действия. **Жду тебя, как (ждут) лучик солнца.** — придаточное сравнительное. В этом предложении пропущено сказуемое придаточного.

Comment: В первом предложении нет сравнения. Придаточное образа действия и степени, *как* - союзное слово.

Comment: Да, вы правы! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

А мне кажется, что первое придаточное является изъяснительным: Ты даже не представляешь (что?), как (сильно) я скучаю, КАК — союзное слово.

Придаточное степени: Я скучаю так сильно, как никогда не скучал. Придаточное образа действия: Я скучаю так, как никогда не скучал.

Но, может быть, я ошибаюсь?